What is the proper way of interpreting "linearizing a differential equation"?
Suppose we have the following differential equation:
$$\ddot{\theta} + \cos{\theta} = 0 \quad,$$
where $\theta$ is an unknown function of a real variable. It isn't uncommon to say we will "linearize" this differential equation around a point, say $\theta = 0$, so that we obtain the following, new differential equation:
$$\ddot{\theta} + 1 = 0 \quad.$$
I understand the motivation and intuition behind this procedure. We're interested in solutions $\theta$ for which $\theta(t)$ is "near" zero, so we build a simpler equation out of the original one, solve this one, and check if this solution is sensible enough for the problem at hand.
However, I get stuck on trying to understand what's really going on behind the scenes.
Linearizing a function is clear enough, so linearizing a conventional equation makes sense. Arrange everything on one side, define a function whose expression is that side, linearize the function around a point of interest, solve the resulting linear equation, and check if the solution will do. I assume the analogy with differential equations would be something like: arrange everything on one side, define a function whose domain is a space of functions, linearize around a function of interest (a constant function?), solve the resulting linear differential equation, and check if the solution will do.
I don't know however what this is supposed to be like. It seems weird to treat functions as if they were real numbers and follow the same procedure for conventional equations and differential equations. In the example at the start of the question, what does $\theta = 0$ really mean? Are we saying we are linearizing around the constant zero function?
I know how to operate this, understand the process intuitively, but don't understand why it works.
EDIT: corrected the example

$\cos\theta\approx 1$ near $\theta=0,.$ The classic example $\ddot\theta+\sin\theta$ is much better. Don't ask such theoretical questions. Take a physics book and look up mathematical pendulum versus physical pendulum.

You are overthinking this. The point is that near the point $\theta = 0$ (say, for $-0.1 < \theta < 0.1$) the function $\sin \theta$ is nearly equal to the function $\theta$ (I am assuming you meant to use $\sin$ instead of $\cos$). So, near the point $\theta = 0$ (again, say for $-0.1 < \theta , 0.1$) the solutions of $\theta'' + \sin \theta = 0$ and of $\theta'' + \theta = 0$ should be nearly identical. This does not involve "treating functions as if they were real numbers", nor does the constant zero function have any connection with this.

@KurtG. I'm not quite sure if your comment is tongue in cheek..?

@Pilcrow Why is this overthinking? I'm just trying to understand a routine process in physics and engineering in a more mathematically rigorous way. I understand the point behind doing it, but I don't understand how to put it in rigorous terms. $\theta$ is a function, not a real number, so what exactly do you mean when you say "the point $\theta = 0$"?

Recall that a differential equation is said to be autonomous if it does not depend on time, that is, if it can be expressed as $$\theta^{(n)}=f\left(\theta,\theta',\ldots,\theta^{(n-1)}\right)$$
for some $C^1$ function $f$.
In these equations, the behaviour of the solutions only depends on the value they take and their derivatives.
Suppose that $f$ only depends on $\theta$, that is, $\theta^{(n)}=f\left(\theta\right)$.
Take a solution that attains some value $\theta_0$. Then (given that $f\in C^1$) a natural way to approximate the behaviour of the equation near that value is replacing $f$ by its first order polynomial around $\theta_0$, that is, linearising the equation.
In your example, $\theta_0=0$ and $f(\theta)=-\cos(\theta)$. As $-\cos(\theta)\sim -1$ when $\theta\to 0$, we can approximate $$\ddot{\theta}=-\cos\theta$$ by $$\ddot{\theta}=-1\iff \ddot{\theta}+1=0$$
The approximation $\ddot{\theta}=-\theta$ would correspond to the case $f(\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$, which is the classic pendulum equation.

Giving an ode as
$$
y' = f(y)
$$
and a function $y^*$,  we can linearize this ode around $y^*$ with the following procedure. As
$$
f(y) = f(y^*) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{y^*}(y-y^*) + O(|y-y^*|^2)
$$
we can approximate around $y^*$
$$
y' = f(y^*) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{y^*}(y-y^*)
$$
Example
$$
\ddot\theta+\sin \theta = 0
$$
Making $y = \left(\matrix{\theta_1\\ \theta_2}\right)$ and $f(y) = \left(\matrix{\theta_2\\ -\sin(\theta_1)}\right)$ and considering $y^* = \left(\matrix{0\\ 0}\right)$ we have
$$
\left(\matrix{\dot \theta_1\\ \dot \theta_2}\right) = \left(\matrix{0\\ 0}\right) + \left(\matrix{0 & 1\\ -\cos(0)& 0}\right)\left(\matrix{\theta_1-0\\ \theta_2-0}\right)
$$
or
$$
\left(\matrix{\dot \theta_1\\ \dot \theta_2}\right) = \left(\matrix{\theta_2\\ -\theta_1}\right)
$$
or equivalently
$$
\ddot\theta + \theta = 0
$$
NOTE
With this procedure we can generate a sequence of linear ode's in $y_k$ which under certain regularity conditions, approach the solution $y$
$$
y'_k = f(y_{k-1})+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{y_{k-1}}(y_k - y_{k-1})
$$

What is the partial derivative of a function of functions, such as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$? Thanks for the answer.

If $f = (f_1,f_2,f_3)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2,y_3)$ we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\left(\matrix{f_{11}&f_{12}&f_{13}\ f_{21}&f_{22}&f_{23}\ f_{31}&f_{32}&f_{33}}\right)$ as in the calculation of a Jacobian.

I mean the domain of $f$ is a space of functions, as in your example ($f(y)$ and linearizing around a function $y^\ast$), not that $f$ evaluates to tuples of real-valued functions.

$y^* = (y_1^,\cdots, y_n^)$

The standard concept of linearizing a first order ODE is the following:
A first order ODE is always of the form:
$$ F(x,y(x),y'(x)) = 0. $$
Suppose you have a solution $y_0$. The linearization of the ODE at $y_0$ is obtained as follows: Assume there is a $1$-parameter family of solutions $y_t$. Therefore,
$$ F(x,y_t,y_t') = 0. $$
The linearization is the derivative of this equation with respect to $t$ evaluated at $t=0$,
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}(x,y_0,y_0')\dot{y}' + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y_0,y_0')\dot{y} = 0.
$$
The ODE
$$ \theta'' + \cos\theta = 0 $$
has a solution
$$ \theta_0(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$
The linearization at $\theta_0$ is
$$ \dot\theta'' - (\sin\theta_0)\dot\theta, $$
i.e.,
$$ \dot\theta'' - \dot\theta = 0. $$
The only way I see to make the linearized equation be
$$ \dot\theta'' + \dot\theta = 0 $$
is to linearize at the solution
$$ \theta_0(x) = -\frac{\pi}{2}. $$
